# Boostrap background not working in CSS, position: fixed also not working

Tags: html, css

I try to place in `div class= "container-fluid"` extra class where I try place background with position fixed...and this is not working.

Only way to place `background-image` is directly to HTML. Why?

Another problem is `position: fixed;`. I use this bootstrap ready to use code like you see in the code below and it is not working, even if I create in **css** and put new class still nothing, what is about?

For example:

```html
<div class="container-fluid position-fixed" style="background-image: 
                url(img/ico/wedding_videography.png); background-size: 
                cover;">
  <div class="row">
```

Answer (score 0):

i just tried to use the same code and it's working but i did it in a different way, here's my code, i hope it helps. https://jsfiddle.net/72reuhaf/1/ and try to add in your code ".." like that:

```
background-image: url(../img/ico/wedding_videography.png);


<div class="container-fluid position-fixed">
 <img class="ferrari" src="https://auto.ferrari.com/ja_JP/wp- 
  content/uploads/sites/10/2015/02/news-ferrari-580x362.jpg" alt="ferrari">
</div>

 body{
 height: 3000px;
 }

.ferrari{
 background-size: cover;
 }
```